# Azure policy definition to restrict users from using or amending from reserved subnet which consists of "123" and "reserved" words in the subnet name

Tags: azure-policy

I am very new to Azure policies and I am looking for azure policy definition which restrict users from using or amending from reserved subnet which consists of  "123" and "reserved" words in the subnet name.

Also, users should not delete the subnet if exist already which contains 'reserved' and '123' in the subnet name.

Which means what we need is deny someone deploying anything under the subnet that having the keyword reserved and 123.

I tried the below but its failing. Not sure if the below one is valid or not.

**Policy definition:**

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets[*].name",
          "matchAny": [
            "123",
            "reserved"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "Deny"
    }
  }
}
```

**Error:**

Failed to parse policy rule: 'Could not find member 'matchAny' on object of type 'LeafExpressionDefinition'. Path 'matchAny'.'.

Could any one please help me on this?

Comment: Is there any update on this please? Its really more important to deliver to implement in Prod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Failed to parse policy rule: 'Could not find member 'matchAny' on object of type 'LeafExpressionDefinition'. Path 'matchAny'.'

Here is the updated policy to restrict the creation of subnets that contain the names **'123'** and **'reserved'**

```json
    {
      "mode": "All",
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "type",
              "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets"
            },
            {
              "field": "name",
              "in": [
                "reserved",
                "123"
              ]
            },
            {
              "anyOf": [
                {
                  "field": "name",
                  "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets[*].name"
                },
                {
                  "field": "name",
                  "contains": "reserved"
                },
                {
                  "field": "name",
                  "contains": "123"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "deny"
        }
      },
      "parameters": {}
    }
```

Once assigned the policy it will deny the deploying Azure subnets that has the keyword `reserved` and `123`.

[image]

If a subnet's name does not match the specified name, it will be marked as `non-compliant`

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response and your solution. I have achieved with separate fields and it worked though.

Can you please help me to exempt/exclude azure group and service pricipal of azure from the above policy?

Say, my azure group name: ABC
Service principal name: def-ghi

Really appreciated!

Comment: Azure policies do not directly support excluding Azure groups or service principals from policy enforcement.

Comment: what is the other way or indirect way to exclude groups or service principals from policy or if the above policy in place how to exempt for service principal or azure groups ?

Comment: You can use **Azure Role-Based Access Control** to define authorization rules and also check for [Deny assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/deny-assignments)